# Redirect to URL inside of browser tab

Tags: acumatica

I need to redirect to a url from Acumatica inside the SAME browser tab. I do not want to have two browser tabs after the redirect. I do not want it to appear inside of the page IFrame, the entire page should be replaced.

I have been using:

```
PXRedirectToUrlException(url, PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.Base/Same/New, "");
PXException($"Redirect#:{url}"); // Replace # with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 etc
```

To no effect.

Thanks
-Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [HTML target frame](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) to `_top` value.

Example:

```
string url = "https://www.acumatica.com";
throw new PXException($"Redirect0:{url}$target=_top");
```